# Как убрать текст в баре над приложением?

Tags: android

***Проблема:*** имею ненужный бар в приложении, к сожалению в `activity_main.xml` вообще нету спрайта с данным баром. Перерыл кучу информации, но так и не нашёл ответа.

[image: ][1]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы наблюдаете `ActionBar`. Он идёт из дефолтного стиля приложения. Вам надо в стилях прописать стиль без `ActionBar` - т.е. `NoActionBar`. Стиль лежит в `app/res/values/theme.xml` (или `styles.xml`). Не забудьте его также правильно приписать  возможно имеющемся файле для ночной тему (`app/res/values-night/theme.xml`)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
   ...
</style>
```